# Keep scrolling the container when mouse stops

Tags: javascript

I have lots of horizontal scroll containers, which I'm moving with mouseover. How can I keep scrolling them while mouse is also stopped in pure javascript?

I tried adding helper function with timeout, but it turned out to animate strangely.

Thanks for your help!

Here is a snippet of code I'm currently using - hover over the rows to scroll them left right.

```js
window.onload = function() {
var gamerow = document.querySelectorAll(".gamerow");
if(gamerow) {

function indexInClass(node) {
  var className = node.className;
  var num = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < gamerow.length; i++) {
    if (gamerow[i] === node) {
      return num;
    }
    num++;
  }
  return -1;
}
 
var scrolla = [0,0,0,0,0,0];

for (var i = 0; i < gamerow.length; i++) { 
var item = gamerow[i]; 

item.addEventListener('mousemove', function scrollHoverly(e) {
 
 e = window.event || e;
var container_w = this.offsetWidth;
var max_scroll = this.scrollWidth - this.offsetWidth;
this.setAttribute("id", "scrolling");
var x = indexInClass(document.getElementById('scrolling'));

var mouse_x = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
var mouseperc = 100 * mouse_x / container_w;
var speed = mouseperc - 50; 


  if (speed !== 0) {
      scrolla[x] += speed / 10;
        if (scrolla[x] < 0) scrolla[x] = 0;
        if (scrolla[x] > max_scroll) scrolla[x] = max_scroll;
      this.scrollLeft = scrolla[x];
  
  }
 
} );

item.addEventListener('mouseleave', function stopHoverly(e) {
 e = window.event || e;
var container_w = this.offsetWidth;
var max_scroll = this.scrollWidth - this.offsetWidth;  
var speed = 0;
this.setAttribute("id", "scrolling");
var x = indexInClass(document.getElementById('scrolling'));
 
  if (speed !== 0) {
      scrolla[x] += speed / 15;
        if (scrolla[x] < 0) scrolla[x] = 0;
        if (scrolla[x] > max_scroll) scrolla[x] = max_scroll;
      this.scrollLeft = scrolla[x];
    }
this.removeAttribute("id","scrolling");
} );

 }
};
};
```

```css
.gamerow {
    padding: 0px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transform: scale(1);
}
.inside {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    margin: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px #adadad;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<container>
<div class="gamerow">
<div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div>
</div>
<div class="gamerow">
<div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div>
</div>
<div class="gamerow">
<div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div>
</div>
<div class="gamerow">
<div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div>
</div>
<div class="gamerow">
<div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div><div class="inside"></div>
</div>
</container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` to call a function repeatedly with a given interval.

I removed the code to update the actual `scrollLeft` attribute from your event handlers and put it into a function that is called every 10 milliseconds (you might want to adjust that interval). I also moved the variable declarations for `x`, `speed` and `max_scroll` outside of your `for` loop so they can be accessed by the new function.

This might not be the best solution performance-wise, but it works.

**Edit:** Moved the call to `setInterval` out of the for loop.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var gamerow = document.querySelectorAll(".gamerow");

  if (gamerow) {

    function indexInClass(node) {
      var className = node.className;
      var num = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < gamerow.length; i++) {
        if (gamerow[i] === node) {
          return num;
        }
        num++;
      }
      return -1;
    }

    var scrolla = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    var x = 0;
    var speed = 0;
    var max_scroll;

    for (var i = 0; i < gamerow.length; i++) {
      var item = gamerow[i];

      item.addEventListener('mousemove', function scrollHoverly(e) {

        e = window.event || e;
        var container_w = this.offsetWidth;
        max_scroll = this.scrollWidth - this.offsetWidth;
        this.setAttribute("id", "scrolling");
        x = indexInClass(this);

        var mouse_x = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
        var mouseperc = 100 * mouse_x / container_w;
        speed = mouseperc - 50;
      });

      item.addEventListener('mouseleave', function stopHoverly(e) {
        e = window.event || e;
        var container_w = this.offsetWidth;
        max_scroll = this.scrollWidth - this.offsetWidth;
        speed = 0;
        x = indexInClass(this);
        this.removeAttribute("id", "scrolling");
      });

    }

    setInterval(function() {
      if (speed !== 0) {
        scrolla[x] += speed / 15;
        if (scrolla[x] < 0) scrolla[x] = 0;
        if (scrolla[x] > max_scroll) scrolla[x] = max_scroll;
        gamerow[x].scrollLeft = scrolla[x];
      }
    }, 10);
  };
};
```

```css
.gamerow {
  padding: 0px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.inside {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px #adadad;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <div class="gamerow">
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gamerow">
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gamerow">
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gamerow">
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gamerow">
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gamerow">
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
    <div class="inside"></div>
  </div>
</container>
```